# s3.getObject not working from dev environment

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

This is my code, which works fine if i run it from my local using local aws account , but it doesn't work from my dev environment. S3.getobject api doesnt get executed and code prints the next log skipping the getobject call  :

```
const unzipFromS3 = (key) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        log.info("inside unzipfroms3");  
        var zlib = require('zlib');
        // let fileName = _.replace(key, 'Root/', '');
        let options = {
            'Bucket': config.bucketName,
            'Key': "Root/" + key,
        }
        log.info("Key:", options);    
        await s3.getObject(options).on('error', error => {
            log.error(error) }).promise().then((res) => {
                yauzl.fromBuffer(res.body, { lazyEntries: true }, function (err, zipfile) {
                    log.info("Inside Yauzl")
                    if (err) throw err;
                    zipfile.readEntry();
                    zipfile.on("entry", function (entry) {
                        if (/\/$/.test(entry.fileName)) {
                            zipfile.readEntry();
                        } else {
                            zipfile.openReadStream(entry, function (err, readStream) {
                                if (err) throw err;
                             // readStream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`result/${entry.fileName}`));
                                readStream
                               .pipe(uploadFromStream(s3));
                                function uploadFromStream(s3) {
                                    log.info("Inside uploadFromStream")
                                    var pass = new Stream.PassThrough();
                                    let options = {
                                       'Bucket': config.bucketName,
                                       'Key': entry.fileName,
                                    }
                                    var params = { ...options, Body: pass };
                                    s3.upload(params, function (err, data) {
                                        log.error(err, data);
                                    });
                                    return pass;
                                    }
                                    readStream.on("end", function () {
                                        zipfile.readEntry();
                                    });
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
      };
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to use `await`, i.e. the promised based version of [S3.getObject()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getObject-property), you must add the `promise()` method to your method call as explained in the [Using JavaScript Promises](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/using-promises.html) chapter of the AWS SDK developer guide. Moreover, there is also an [Using async/await](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/using-async-await.html) chapter that you can look into.

In your case, the code can be modified to something like:

```js
await s3.getObject(options).promise()
    .then((res) => {
        yauzl.fromBuffer(/* more code */);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks matsev, i am using it exactly like you mentioned above, still nothing.

Comment: Try check for any error returned by the promise e.g. `.promise().then((res) => { yawl.fromBuffer(...);}, (err) => {console.log('S3.getObject()' failed:', err); } )`